# ajax not working in breezing forms component of joomla

Tags: joomla1.6, breezingforms

```
function ff_chk_username_unique(element, action)
{
alert(element.value);
alert(action);
var actiona="http://localhost/myproject/check/check_username.php";
var form_data = {
            username: element.value,
        };
alert(actiona);

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: actiona,
            data: form_data,
                        success: function(response)
            {
                           alert(response)

            }
        });

} // ff_chk_username_unique
```

code of my ajax file...

file is not called within ajax,

is ajax defined properly?? please help me solve it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's working in breezingforms but you need to add jquery file when you use ajax...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your answer? Thanks

Comment: yes where you want to use jquery ajax. Add jquery files in that file using addscript() kind function of joomla